# Call Android Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, phone-call, dialing

I have an application that performs a phone call, but when I send dial directly, the application is in the background and displays the screen of the android default phone call, it must not happen, because when the phone call is made, I need to trigger commands that are in my application. If anyone knows of a possible solution. Thank you.
Below is the my method used to perform a phone call.

```
private void call() {
try {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
     Log.e("Dialing", "Call failed", e);
}
```

}

Comment: You need to trigger code 'as' the call is happening or 'after' the call? And what do you need to do?

Comment: This code is triggered when I press the call button in my application, after that, android should make the call and stay in my application, does not change to the default android call screen.

Comment: If you want the call to happen within your app, then you have to write your own dialer, not an easy task. `Intent`s allow you to ask other apps to perform actions for you, but they cannot integrate within another app's activity, and allow for modification. So you either need to rethink your design, or write your own dialer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I got your question right. If you are trying to create an app to replace default phone call handling app, then I guess you should know that it's not a cake walk.

Firstly let me make it clear that you simply can't create a phone app to replace default app.

If you really want to do it then you need to get the Android source code, recompile it by adding your phone app and flash it on a rooted device.

Comment: In the scenario in which I find myself is that my application will trigger the same DTMF keypad of Android, would be a kind of customized keyboard, where instead of buttons with numbers, there would be buttons with images and labels that when pressed acionariam DTMF tones so the user has to adapt more quickly and accurately to use the application.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, you cannot do "stealth" calls without dialer showing up.